# Cant Get Twitter Bootstrap Collapse To Work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone please help me get this to work. It appears that I have it setup exactly how it suggests in the Twitter Bootstrap docs but The Collapse on a navbar nav is not working for me. I have no special styles setup that would interfere with it working as well. What is happening is when I make the screen smaller or view on a mobile device the menu does not collapse as it should.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse"  id="masthead">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="brand muted" >Redding Salon</div>
      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" id="navbar" >
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#make_an_appointment">Make An Appointment</a></li>
          <li><a href="#meet_the_stylist">Meet The Stylists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact_us">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in my heaeder I have the following all of which are in the respected areas and getting added properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include [`Twitter Bootstrap` responsive CSS](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css) and [collapse js](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js). And optionally [transition js](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js).

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/PD4kg/

Comment: That was it but how come its not in bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: I don't know, maybe you didn't checked that part when you've downloaded custom code.

Answer (score 0):

change the href and src path directory from ( href="assets/ & src="assets/js/ ) to your own path directoy. hope this help